# Passing variable using ajax and open next page

Tags: php, ajax

I try passing variable from one page to next using ajax.
I have running passing, but I don't know how to open page with this variable.

My actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="test" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Test</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#test").click(function () {
            var variable = 'AAAaaa';
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'view.php',
                data: {"temp": variable},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success!");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And second page where I want watching what is in $_Post table

```
<?php
$table = $_POST;
?>

<pre>
    <?= print_r($table);?>
</pre>
```

Edit for comment:

> Not a problem. You can create a callback function inside ajax's
>   success event. On success, take that data from view.php and send it to
>   the second page with another ajax call. It will all be done
>   asynchronously and accomplish what you're asking for. – putipong

I have array in view. For example:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

How to send via post and ajax this array to controller function and open this action, when I press the button. 
I tried as above , but does not work

```
 public function actionUuuu()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $array = $request->post();

        print_r($array)
```

Comment: You don't need ajax for this, passing values from one page to the other is what forms do natively

Comment: didn't get your exact requirement, what you needed.. you don't require ajax for redirecting. be brief to fill question info.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to redirect to another page and pass that variable? OR are you trying to stay on the current page? Why are you trying to use AJAX? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

In your **view.php**, you can assign the table data to `$_SESSION` and then retrieve later in your second page, simply by starting a session with **session_start();**

A session must be started on every page that requires the use of session data, else it will not work.

**view.php:**

```
session_start();
if ($_POST['temp'] == 'AAAaaa') {
    $_SESSION['tableData'] = $tableData;
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
return;
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#test").click(function () {
        var variable = 'AAAaaa';
        //alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'view.php',
            data: {"temp": variable},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'true') {
                     window.location.replace('secondPage.php');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**secondPage.php**

```
session_start();
$table = $_SESSION['tableData'];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have big array in view and I want pass this array from view to another controller. I'm using yii2 framework so I started with the simple example above.I want use button and ajax to pass aray to another controller.

Comment: Not a problem. You can create a callback function inside ajax's success event. On success, take that data from view.php and send it to the second page with another ajax call. It will all be done asynchronously and accomplish what you're asking for.

Comment: I edit my question about yii. I don't know how do this in yii2 framework